# Importing into SVN, either get file exists or file not found error

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I've filtered the dump file like this:

`svndumpfilter include /config-tool/trunk < aps.dump > ct-filtered.dump`

First try, create repo and 3 folders:

```
svnadmin create myrepo
svn mkdir file:///home/me/myrepo/folderA file:///home/me/myrepo/folderA/config-tool file:///home/me/myrepo/folderA/config-tool/trunk -m "Go"

Committed revision 1.

svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem '/home/me/myrepo/db', transaction '12-c', path 'folderA/config-tool/trunk'
     * adding path : folderA/config-tool/trunk
```

Second try, create repo and only folderA

```
svnadmin create myrepo
svn mkdir file:///home/me/myrepo/folderA -m "Go"

Committed revision 1.

svnadmin load --parent-dir folderA /home/me/myrepo < /home/me/ct-filtered.dump

svnadmin: File not found: transaction '12-c', path 'folderA/config-tool/trunk'
     * adding path : folderA/config-tool/trunk
```

I've read quite a few threads on SO about this, not quite sure what I'm missing.

In the dump itself, I confirmed the paths are present:

`Node-path: config-tool/trunk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the second case you've specified, the following will work:

Note that we are creating `folderA/config-tool`, not just `folderA`.

1. `svndumpfilter include /config-tool/trunk < aps.dump > ct-filtered.dump`
2. `svnadmin create myrepo`
3. `svn mkdir file:///home/me/myrepo/folderA/config-tool --parents -m "Go"`
4. `svnadmin load --parent-dir folderA myrepo < ct-filtered.dump`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have to specify --skip-missing-merge-sources when using svndumpfilter. But yeah, this seems to work. So, first try without the creation of trunk would have worked...